# Keras - Can't freed my input data to keras model. Error when checking input

Tags: python, keras, supervised-learning

I'm trying to learn my Keras model truth tables. It is only to learn a bit more about Keras so this example is just for learning purposes. My input looks like this:

```
x = np.array([
    [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1]
    ],
    [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
    ],
    [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0]
    ],
    [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0]
    ],
    [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0]
    ], 
    [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    ]
])

y = np.array([['AND'],['OR'],['NAND'], ['NOR'], ['XOR'], ['XNOR']])
```

When I feed it into my first layer I do the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(72, input_shape=(6, 4, 3)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(6))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=32)
```

My input shape so 6 gates each with 4 rows and 3 cols and a Dense layer of 72 because 6 * 4 * 3. Now when I execute this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_32_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6, 4, 3)
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how in the future I should feed my data into Keras?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input_shape in your first dense layer should be (4, 3) instead of (6, 4, 3). The first dimension (6 in your case) is for the batch size, which you should not specify in the input shape.

There are also more problems with your model. You probably want to use softmax instead of sigmoid at your output layer. Secondly, your `y` vector with labels should have numeric values. For example, you can represent each word with an integer index instead. Thirdly, I think you want a Flatten layer in the beginning of your model to flatten your rank 2 input tensor to a rank 1 tensor.

Comment: Thanks Anna, but I tried that but then it will complain about: Error when checking target: expected activation_44 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (6, 1)

Comment: I have edited my answer with some suggestions on how to improve your model. The problem you are having here is probably because you didn't flatten your input before the dense layer.

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks for the suggestions, It is now possible to train the model. Thanks for the explainations!